Reverse polarity protection on a 5 V LED strip supply
I'm looking to use an AOD413A (P Channel MOSFET) as reverse polarity protection on my LED strip controller which uses 7.7 A at 5 V DC. I think I partially understand how to choose the right one, but I'm not 100% confident.
The AOD413A datasheet states continuous current is 12 A with a Vth of -1.7 to -3 V, max Vgs ±20 V. I'm reading this to mean I should not need a resistor or diode to protect the gate. Would the following circuit work fine — and is it overkill or a good fit?

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

"Is it overkill"? Do you expect to accidentally connect the controller backwards? Lots of people design in reverse polarity protection "just in case" but if you are hooking this up once and leaving it, then there's not really a strong argument for this level of protection that I can see. Even if you're connecting and disconnecting it frequently, a polarized connector will prevent 99% of accidents.

This is a good point, I totally agree

not disagreeing with that at all, but it's for a hobbyist product and looking to harden the design a little bit beyond the physical connector.

As you are using 5V to power up your circuit I will use a logic level mosfet like this one https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ntd25p03l-d.pdf for reverse polarity protection.
Assuming the 5V is from a stable supply, a zener diode will not be required to protect the gate, although is a good practice to include one.
Regarding to use or not a resistor on the gate, my advice is always include one to prevent ringing (there are various posts on the site you can search about this).
In your scenario a 20ohm or bigger resistor would be a good fit.

is there any particular advantage to choosing a logic level mostfet? I noticed the NTD25P03L has 3x the cost ($1.36) vs the AOD413A at $0.40. The AOD413A has a drive voltage of 4.5V and I'm assuming this will play nice on a 5V supply.

The key difference with logic-level power MOSFETs is that VGS(TH) is much lower, typically between 1.2 and 2.2 V. The maximum VGS ratings are still +20 and -20 V. The advantage is that such devices can be driven with logic-level gate drive voltage, typically 5V in applications where a higher voltage is not available. Based in the gate voltage threshold of your selected mosfet, for this particular scenario I think will work ok.

The concept is good, the implementation with an AOD413A will require some form of a heat sink to be a practical solution.
MOSFET datasheets - Id max can only be attained on a constant basis with sufficient heat sinking  to keep the die temperature in a safe range - all those footnotes matter.  Data sheets paint a rosy picture but do also give the information needed to do a proper design.
AOD413A - 40V, 12A, 66mohm, DPAK.  Theta JA = 50C/W Theta JC = 3C/W (with their given constraints). ID max = 7.7A. Work the math.  You will need a significant heat sink to keep Tj within spec.
I'd look for a PMOS with an Rds 1/10 of the AO413 to keep the MOSFET Tj within 20 degrees.  That device will cost more, but will eliminate the need for a heat sink.  If you want to rely on a heat sink to limit the MOSFET Tj, your thermal design will get complicated(and expensive) quickly.
